# Why does ASP.NET MVC Html.CheckBox output two INPUTs with the same name?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Why in the world does the line:

```
<%= Html.CheckBox("ForSale", Model.Product.ForSale)%> For Sale
```

result in the following HTML:

```
<input id="ForSale" name="ForSale" type="checkbox" value="true" />
<input name="ForSale" type="hidden" value="false" />
For Sale
```

Now whenever I check the box and access `Request.Form["ForSale"]`, I get the ridiculous answer of `"true,false"`. Am I supposed to parse that?

This hidden field doesn't appear for the other HtmlHelper controls, so why does it for CheckBox?

**How do I turn this stupid "feature" off?** Or did the `HtmlHelper` just outgrow its usefulness?

**Update**

From the answer below, it seems that there is some logic behind this. I have prepared a little extension method so I don't have to think about it (thanks to @eu-ge-ne):

```
    public static bool GetCheckBoxValue(this System.Web.HttpRequestBase req, 
                                        string name) {
        return Convert.ToBoolean(req.Form.GetValues(name).First());
    }
```

Comment: If you're using Request.Form, you're probably doing it wrong.

Comment: +1 - I just ran into this issue the other day as well.  Seems like they were trying to be helpful but just ended up annoying those of us that actually know how checkboxes are supposed to work.

Comment: @mgroves mind posting an answer to let me know what it is that I'm probably doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you just put the boolean in your action method signature and let model binding do the work for you?

Comment: Well it's not an answer to your question is why :) I would suggest using the model binder (i.e. what Brad said).

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It forces the field to be included if it's unchecked. If you uncheck a check box it doesn't get sent as part of the page - they are only sent if they're checked, and then there's a value of true. The hidden field ensures that false will be send if the check box is unchecked, as the hidden field is always sent.

Comment: So I am supposed to parse the string?

Comment: You should not parse the string, neither use the Request object directly in your action:just use a boolean as one of your action method parameters and everything will be handled for you

Comment: To expand: if your action method’s signature is like `public ActionResult b(bool b = false)`, then the extra generated `<input/>` makes no difference. If your action method’s signature is `public ActionResult b(bool b = true)` or `public ActionResult b(bool b)`, then `b` will be set `false` if the checkbox is included but unchecked on a particular form and `b` will be set `true` or generate an error, respectively, on forms where you don’t include the checkbox. This `Html.CheckBox()` behavior ensures that “unchecked” always properly maps onto `false` and that the form matches the action method.

Answer (score 6):

I took a different approach:

Do not use the Html.CheckBoxFor or Html.CheckBox helper method to render a checkbox, but render it using normal html:

```
<input id="ShowOther" name="ShowOther" value="<%=Model.ShowOther %>" type="checkbox" <% if (Model.ShowOther)  { %>checked="checked"<% } %> />
```

And I've added a jQuery script which sets the value when the **checkbox** is checked/unchecked.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#ShowOther').click(function() {
            var checked = $(this).attr('checked');
            if (checked != undefined)
                $(this).val(true);
            else
                $(this).val(false);
        });
    });
</script>
```

As far as I could test this, it seems that the correct **value** is always sent to the Controller, and no more issues with *"true,false"*.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I've done it in one of my apps. Frustrating, but it seems to work.

```
public virtual ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection values)
{
    SomeObject dbData = _repository.GetSomeObject(id);

    try
    {
        UpdateModel(dbData);
        if (values.GetValues("CheckBoxId").Contains("true")) 
            dbData.SomeBooleanProperty = true;
        else 
            dbData.SomeBooleanProperty = false;

        _repository.Save();

        Session["Success"] = "Successfully edited the part.";
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch
    {
        // Handle validation errors here
        return View(new SomeObjectFormViewModel(dbData));
    }
}
```

Hope this helps. If you've got any follow-up questions, just leave a comment and I'll update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

If a CheckBox is not checked, then it will not be included in the form submission. So this "feature" gives you a result for every CheckBox.  Those that are not checked will be simply "false".

I have implemented my own CheckBox helper functions that work differently.  Most of the time I don't want just true or false, but just a collection of the values of the checked boxes.  It's great for selecting certain items by their id on which to perform an action.  I don't want the unchecked items even in the list.

You can take a look at the source code for the html extensions and use a similar structure to create your own CheckBox methods.

http://aspnet.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/changeset/view/23011?projectName=aspnet#288010

I would post mine, but I'm not using the standard HtmlHelper class, so it would probably be more confusing.  I did add a value parameter to my CheckBox functions so that I can use a specific id value instead of "true" or "false".

Answer (score 2):

> Now whenever I check the box and access Request.Form["ForSale"], I get the ridiculous answer of "true,false". Am I supposed to parse that?

Try this:

```
var ForSale = Convert.ToBoolean(Request.Form.GetValues("ForSale").First());
```

**UPDATED:**

> What if in the next MVC build it will return the value in the revers order "false, true"? ... – Mastermind

```
var ForSale = Request.Form.GetValues("ForSale")
    .Select(x => x.ToUpperInvariant()).Contains("TRUE");

// or

// FormatException can be thrown from Convert.ToBoolean()
var ForSale = Request.Form.GetValues("ForSale")
    .Select(x => Convert.ToBoolean(x)).Contains(true);
```

Comment: What if in the next MVC build it will return the value in the revers order "false, true"? It's a workable but not reliable solution. Which is why I abandoned the built-in helpers and did my own.

Comment: @Frank Krueger - hope not in MVC2

Answer (score 0):

try

`request.form["chkBoxes"].replace("false","").split(new char[] {','}, stringsplitoptions.removeemptyentries);`

Answer (score 0):

I think the cleanest solution is to do:

```
(bool)formCollection["key"].ConvertTo(typeof(bool))
```