# why is checkbox always true

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using  `@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Luxury)`

which generates the following HTML

```
<input id="Luxury" type="checkbox" value="true" name="Luxury" data-val-required="The Luxury field is required." data-val="true">
<input type="hidden" value="true" name="Luxury">
```

So no matter what I set the check box to the controllers action is getting the value as TRUE, even when not checked.

How do I get MVC not to make a checkbox return true.
When I debug on the first Brace even before I call any code I can see Banner.Luxury is always = true

My Class

```
   public class Banner
   {
         public int Id { get; set; }
         public bool Luxury { get; set; }
   }



[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(Banner banner)

       ....
}
```

Looking at this question [Why does ASP.NET MVC Html.CheckBox output two INPUTs with the same name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127357/why-does-asp-net-mvc-html-checkbox-output-two-inputs-with-the-same-name) does not help as when I run

```
Convert.ToBoolean(Request.Form.GetValues("Luxury"));
```

There is only "true"  not "true;false";

**This workaround works but its a bad HACK**

```
 @{      if (Model.Luxury)
         {
                 <input type="checkbox" name="Luxury" value="1" checked="checked" />
         }
         else
         {
                  <input type="checkbox" name="Luxury" value="1" />
         }
   }
```

code

```
 banner.Luxury = !(Request.Form.GetValues("Luxury") == null);
```

Comment: It's more likely the problem lies in your action, so you'd want to post the code of that. Checkboxes in HTML are likely to not work the way your action assumes they do (i.e., if you're manually binding its value to the model, you're likely to be doing it wrong).

Comment: @TheKaneda I add more code to my question however I am not doing anything in the code. I use this similar code on many other pages and it works ok.

Comment: No, because if your hidden value was false, even when you ticked the checkbox you'd still get false from 'Luxury', as the LAST field with a name takes precedence.

Comment: Let's just make it clear: The order doesn't matter, and the order used here works on tens of thousands of webpages using it. What matters is that that hidden input has "true" as its value - which it shouldn't.

Comment: I'd really like to see your entire view then - maybe on codetidy.com or similar (yeah, I know we'd like questions to be self-contained, but it may not have anything to do with the problem, and would probably make the question really lengthy).

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?? I am getting the same. I get true whether the checkbox is checked or not back when the form is posted server side.

Comment: @MoXplod I just stuck with the workaround I mentioned in the question

Comment: Ahh that sucks. I was getting the same problem, i decided to create a EditorTemplate for boolean, where instead of a checkbox, by default it has a drop down with Yes/No values

Comment: It took me a while to figure this out for myself before having a "duh" moment. If you are using AJAX to post your form, your JavaScript has to account for the hidden element, or at least ignore the hidden element and send false when the checkbox isn't checked.

Answer (score 1):

Change it to:

```
<input type="hidden" value="false" name="Luxury">
<input id="Luxury" type="checkbox" value="true" name="Luxury" data-val-required="The Luxury field is required." data-val="true">
```

That way when you chek the checkbox it will become true, otherwise it will be false.   The order of controls matters.

**In your example even if you changed the order, you were always returning true.**

Comment: The HTML is generated - and correct - so it shouldn't be (and can't be) changed.

Comment: I can change the HTML manually but that will be pretty ugly since the rest of my code is using the razor @Html.CheckBoxFor syntax to generate HTML. How can do this with in ASP/Razor

Comment: Auto-generated or not, if you that hidden input box appears AFTER the related checkbox, the hidden input value will ALWAYS be used.  My way, it will only be used if the checkbox is NOT ticked.  As it should be. http://iamcam.wordpress.com/2008/01/15/unchecked-checkbox-values/\

Comment: Well, I take back the "HTML is correct" part, because what's true about twilson's answer is that the hidden input shouldn't contain "true"... ETA: As for "ALWAYS", nope. The hidden input will only be used if the checkbox isn't checked - no matter if it's before or after.

Comment: I'll balance the scale on the votes here with an upvote, because, like I said in another comment - this workaround (if the `<input>`s are swapped) at least should work better than the one Daveo suggests himself.

Answer (score 0):

You're saying `CheckBoxFor` outputs this code:

```
<input type="hidden" value="true" name="Luxury">
```

I have a very hard time seeing how it would do that, considering the code to generate that helper field is this (in `InputHelper` called by `CheckBoxHelper` called by `CheckBoxFor`):

```
if (inputType == InputType.CheckBox) {
    StringBuilder inputItemBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    inputItemBuilder.Append(tagBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));

    TagBuilder hiddenInput = new TagBuilder("input");
    hiddenInput.MergeAttribute("type", 
       HtmlHelper.GetInputTypeString(InputType.Hidden));
    hiddenInput.MergeAttribute("name", fullName);
    hiddenInput.MergeAttribute("value", "false"); // <-- Notice this
    inputItemBuilder.Append(hiddenInput.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(inputItemBuilder.ToString());
}
```

Notice that it's explicitly setting `value` to "false" - it's not getting the value for the hidden field from anywhere. So, unless you have your own `CheckBoxFor` method - or some other shenanigans going on - I don't see how it would end up being "true".

But yes, as long as that "hidden" input *is* "true", `Luxury` will end up being always true.

When the checkbox is checked, the checkbox's value - and the hidden value, which MVC will ignore - is sent (`Luxury=true&Luxury=true` - or the POST equivalent).

When it's unchecked, only the hidden value is sent (`Luxury=true`).

This is why the hidden input should be `false` - so that `Luxury=false` is sent when the checkbox is unchecked. Again, the question is, why *isn't* it `false`?

The explanation for that lies somewhere in your code that we haven't seen.

Comment: me neither. I just checked all my code to see it I override  any of the extensions and I do not. I can workaround the issue by updated my question with

Comment: If you're going without the helpers anyway, @twilson's workaround works too (just swap the `<input>`s for MVC) - it also avoids the need to manually check the Request in your action, because everything is then how the model binder expects it to be.